# Linker and architecture type errors on Solaris

Tags: architecture, linker, solaris

On my solaris 64 bit machine I'm creating an executable "drivertest" (1) by linking 3 object files drivermain.o (2), testcol.o (3) and teststmt.o (3). I have used the -m64 option in the commands to create 64 bit executable. When I try to run the executable I get the error "Illegal Instruction (core dumped)". When I try to view the core using dbx command it says "dbx: File `drivertest' is not ELF executable". My executable is 64 bit, so why can't dbx work with 64 bit application?

Also when I run the ldd command on the executable it gives a "file not found" error for several dependencies (4) , all of which are there in /export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r (5) and this directory is included in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH that has been exported using the setenv command.
Why does this happen also?

```
(1)
CC -G -m64 -o drivertest SunOS.64.r/drivermain.o SunOS.64.r/testcol.o SunOS.64.r/teststmt.o  \
 -L/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r -L/databases/oracle10.2.0_64BIT/lib -L/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ACE/ace -L/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r  \
 -lpmcuti -lpmasrt -lpmser -lpmi18n -lpmdec -lpmodl -lclntsh -lpmicudata -lpmicui18n -lpmicuio -lpmicuuc -lpmsdkcmn



(2)
CC +w +w2 -mt -features=extensions -erroff=doubunder -m64 -O  -KPIC -m64 -D_REENTRANT -DRW_MULTI_THREAD -DRW_NO_STL -DRW_BCB_NEW_IOSTREAMS -DPM_64BIT -DFD_SETSIZE=65536 -DUNIX -DSunOS -DINFA_PREFIX -I. -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dwriter -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dwriter/wrtfile -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/include/cef -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dmapper/trans -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dmapper/scrub -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dreader -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/cmnutils -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/common/cmnmisc -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/mitkerberos/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/CURL/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/OPENSSL/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/PMTL_PC -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/STLPORT_INCLUDE/stlport -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ICU/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ICU/source/common \
        -c /home/devops/drivertest/drivermain.cpp -o SunOS.64.r/drivermain.o

(3)            
CC +w +w2 -mt -features=extensions -erroff=doubunder -m64 -O  -KPIC -m64 -D_REENTRANT -DRW_MULTI_THREAD -DRW_NO_STL -DRW_BCB_NEW_IOSTREAMS -DPM_64BIT -DFD_SETSIZE=65536 -DUNIX -DSunOS -DINFA_PREFIX -I. -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dwriter -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dwriter/wrtfile -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/include/cef -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dmapper/trans -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dmapper/scrub -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dreader -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/cmnutils -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/common/cmnmisc -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/mitkerberos/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/CURL/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/OPENSSL/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/PMTL_PC -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/STLPORT_INCLUDE/stlport -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ICU/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ICU/source/common \
        -c /home/devops/drivertest/testcol.cpp -o SunOS.64.r/testcol.o

(4)
CC +w +w2 -mt -features=extensions -erroff=doubunder -m64 -O  -KPIC -m64 -D_REENTRANT -DRW_MULTI_THREAD -DRW_NO_STL -DRW_BCB_NEW_IOSTREAMS -DPM_64BIT -DFD_SETSIZE=65536 -DUNIX -DSunOS -DINFA_PREFIX -I. -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dwriter -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dwriter/wrtfile -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/include/cef -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dmapper/trans -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dmapper/scrub -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/dreader -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/server/cmnutils -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/common/cmnmisc -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/mitkerberos/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/CURL/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/OPENSSL/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/PMTL_PC -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/STLPORT_INCLUDE/stlport -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ICU/include -I/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ICU/source/common \
        -c /home/devops/drivertest/teststmt.cpp -o SunOS.64.r/teststmt.o

(5)
psrux902b1% ldd drivertest
    libpmcuti.so =>  (file not found)
    libpmasrt.so =>  (file not found)
    libpmser.so =>   (file not found)
    libpmi18n.so =>  (file not found)
    libpmdec.so =>   (file not found)
    libpmodl.so =>   (file not found)
    libclntsh.so.10.1 =>     /databases/oracle10.2.0_64BIT/lib/libclntsh.so.10.1
    libpmicudata.so.32 =>    /export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ICU/lib/libpmicudata.so.32
    libpmicui18n.so.32 =>    /export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ICU/lib/libpmicui18n.so.32
    libpmicuio.so.32 =>      /export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ICU/lib/libpmicuio.so.32
    libpmicuuc.so.32 =>      /export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/repo/third-party-libs/ICU/lib/libpmicuuc.so.32
    libpmsdkcmn.so =>        (file not found)
    libnnz10.so =>   /databases/oracle10.2.0_64BIT/lib/libnnz10.so
    libkstat.so.1 =>         /lib/64/libkstat.so.1
    libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/64/libnsl.so.1
    libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/64/libsocket.so.1
    libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/64/libgen.so.1
    libdl.so.1 =>    /lib/64/libdl.so.1
    libsched.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/64/libsched.so.1
    libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/64/libaio.so.1
    librt.so.1 =>    /lib/64/librt.so.1
    libm.so.2 =>     /lib/64/libm.so.2
    libc.so.1 =>     /lib/64/libc.so.1
    libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/sparcv9/libpthread.so.1
    libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/64/libmp.so.2
    libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/64/libmd.so.1
    libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/64/libscf.so.1
    libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/64/libdoor.so.1
    libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/64/libuutil.so.1
    /platform/SUNW,T5240/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1
    /platform/SUNW,T5240/lib/sparcv9/libmd_psr.so.1


(6)
psrux902b1% ls /export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r/libpmasrt.so
/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r/libpmasrt.so
psrux902b1% ls /export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r/libpmser.so
/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r/libpmser.so
psrux902b1%  ls /export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r/libpmi18n.so
/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r/libpmi18n.so
psrux902b1%  ls /export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r/libpmdec.so
/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r/libpmdec.so
psrux902b1% ls /export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r/libpmodl.so
/export/home/builds/pc9x_root/960/build/powrmart/pmbuild/bin/SunOS.64.r/libpmodl.so
```

Comment: On Solaris, dbx comes with the Studio compilers - which compiler version are you using the dbx from?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `file(1)` to check what type of ELF binary which object/executable is. If you try to mix 32b and 64b ELF object's it's not going to work (i.e. if libpmcuti.so is a 32b object and your executable is 64b). Also make sure that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is actually exported. Since you use -m64, it seems your toolchain is 32b by default: dbx might be 32b as well, and fails to work with 64b executables?

Comment: file command does say /usr/bin/dbx is 32 bit, but where do I find the 64 bit dbx?

Comment: Studio's dbx command is smart enough to re-exec itself from $STUDIOHOME/prod/bin/$MACH64  if it detects that you want it to run over a 64bit file.